# how to close a popup dialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a simple text of code in my `main.class` file which creates a `popup` dialog. When I try to close the popupdialog with `finish();` method, it shuts down the whole application, and not only the popup dialog box. How can i solve this ? ( this is for android, look at my comments below aswell ).

This is the code:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.start_dialog);
 dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
 dialog.setCancelable(true);

 //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

 //set up text

 TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
 text.setText(R.string.loss);

 //set up image view
 ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.golf_ball);

 //set up button
 Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                                  finish();
                        }
                });
   //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
         dialog.show();
```

Comment: What programming language/OS/environment/etc ?

Comment: android mobile ( JAVA ).

Answer (score 0):

Jesmar,

Hello and welcome.

You probably intended to use the [`dismiss`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) function on your `Dialog`.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                                  dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                });
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                                  finish();
                        }
                });
```

actually that finish() is belong to your activity, not your dialog. do dialog.dismiss() instead

Answer (score 0):

Use cancel() or dismiss()

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                                  dialog.cancel();
                        }
                });
```

or

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                                  dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                });
```